# Matrix multiplication: $X_{r \times c}$ and $Y_{c \times d}$

Tags: matrices

Matrix $X$ has $r$ rows and $c$ columns, and matrix $Y$ has $c$ rows and $d$ columns, where $r, c$, and $d$ are different. Which of the following must be ***false***?

1. The product $YX$ exists
2. The product of $XY$ exists and has $r$ rows and $d$ columns
3. The product $XY$ exists and has $c$ rows and $c$ columns

The answer says only 2 is false, but isn't 2 the only correct choice?

Comment: Choose values that satisfy the constraints, like $r = 1$, $c = 2$, $d = 3$.  Make two matrices that satisfy those dimensions.  Multiply them.

Comment: You are right about 2nd, but 1st is also, technically, true.

Comment: I happened to write "XY" instead of "YX" for 1.

Comment: Something seems wrong here, because 2. is the only TRUE statement here (by definition of matrix multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

It helps to visualize matrix multiplication:

[image]
(courtesy of [Wikimedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Matrix_multiplication_diagram.svg))

The number of columns of the first multiplicand has to match the number of rows of the second multiplicand.

Looking at the three choices:

1. **The product YX exists**
   This would require that $d$ the number of columns in Y equals the number $r$ of 
   rows in X.
   Since $r \ne d$, this is not the case.
2. **The product of XY exists and has $r$ rows and $d$ columns**
   Since $c = c$, the product exists. It has in fact $r$ rows and $d$ columns.
3. **The product XY exists and has $c$ rows and $c$ columns**
   Since $c = c$, the product exists. But it has $r$ rows and $d$ columns.

Therefore, choice 2 is the only true one.